# What is the result of this equation?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any sensitive equation solver which will not show the result as approximately $0$ for this equation:

$$\cos x=e^{-\Large\frac{3}{10^{45}}}$$

or how can I calculate it?

Comment: Mathematica can probably do it for you.  I must ask, why isn't 0 a sufficiently accurate answer?

Comment: Need for a physical calculation

Comment: PARI/GP is already powerful enough (even with standard precision) to calculate this.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent approximation for $$\arccos(e^{-x})$$ for $x\approx 0$ is $$\sqrt{2x}$$ (In the case you have to calculate such things in the future only having access to a normal calculator)

In your example, the difference between the values is about $4\cdot 10^{-68}$. Even, if $x$ is , for example $0.001$ , the error is less than $10^{-5}$.

Comment: Where does this approximation come from? I've never run across it, and it seems rather powerful.

Comment: Look here, this might be an explanation : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(sqrt(2x))-exp(-x)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to solve $x$:

$$\cos(x)=\text{K}\Longleftrightarrow x=2\pi\text{n}\pm\arccos\left(\text{K}\right)$$

Where $\text{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$

So, when $\text{K}=e^{-\frac{3}{10^{45}}}$:

$$\cos(x)=e^{-\frac{3}{10^{45}}}\Longleftrightarrow x=2\pi\text{n}\pm\arccos\left(e^{-\frac{3}{10^{45}}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want a numerical approximation like you asked, SageMath can do it for you.

You will find:

$$x\approx 7.7459666924148337703585307995647992216658\times 10^{-23}.$$

Comment: thanks I was looking for like this solution