# Why is $\arccos(e^{-x})\approx \sqrt{2x}$ for $x\approx 0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation

Here

[What is the result of this equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987949/what-is-the-result-of-this-equation/1988027#1988027)

I mentioned the approximation $$\arccos(e^{-x})\approx \sqrt{2x}\ for\ \  x\approx 0$$

but I could not give a reason, why this is the case , with calculation by hand.

> How can I justify the given approximation by hand ?

I tried the taylor-series but the function $\arccos(e^{-x})$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Do I need a substitution, or the expansion of $\arccos^2(e^{-x})$ ?
Or can I expand $\arccos(e^{-x})$ directly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y=\arccos e^{-x}$ then $e^{-x}=\cos(y)=1-2\sin^2\frac y2$ and from that
$$
y=2\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{1-e^{-x}}2}
$$
Now employ Taylor approximations $2\arcsin(u)=2u+\frac13u^3+O(u^5)$ and 
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1-e^{-x}}2}=\sqrt{\frac x2}\sqrt{1-\frac12x+O(x^2)}
=\sqrt{\frac x2}(1-\frac14 x+O(x^2))
$$
to get approximatively
\begin{align}
y&=\sqrt{2x}(1-\frac14 x+O(x^2))+\frac13\frac{x\sqrt{2x}}4+O(x^{5/2})\\
\arccos e^{-x}&=\sqrt{2x}(1-\frac16 x+O(x^2))
\end{align}

---

$$\scriptsize
\arccos e^{-x}=\sqrt{2x}·\left(1 - \frac16 x + \frac1{120}x^2 + \frac1{336}x^3 - \frac1{5760}x^4 - \frac{19}{126720}x^5 + O(x^6)\right)
$$

Comment: +1 and accept because of the expansion of $\arccos(e^{-x})$

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you cannot use a Taylor expansion around $0$ is the fact that $\arccos \Bbb e ^{-x}$ is *not* defined to the left of $0$ (where $\Bbb e ^{-x} > 1$, and $\arccos$ is defined only on $[-1,1]$).

One way is to show that

$$\lim \limits _{x \to 0, x > 0} \frac {\arccos \Bbb e ^{-x}} {\sqrt {2x}} = 1 .$$

Since this is a case of $\frac 0 0$, the usual procedure goes through l'Hospital's theorem:

$$\lim \limits _{x \to 0, x > 0} \frac {\arccos \Bbb e ^{-x}} {\sqrt {2x}} = \lim \limits _{x \to 0, x > 0} \frac {\sqrt {2x}} {-\sqrt {1 - \Bbb e ^{-2x}}} (- \Bbb e ^{-x}) = \lim \limits _{x \to 0, x > 0} \frac {\sqrt {2x}} {\sqrt {\Bbb e ^{2x} -1}} = \\
\sqrt {\lim \limits _{x \to 0, x > 0} \frac {2x} {\Bbb e ^{2x} -1}} = \dots$$

and applying l'Hospital's theorem again under the square root gives

$$\dots = \sqrt {{\lim \limits _{x \to 0, x > 0} \frac 2 {2 \Bbb e ^{2x}}}} = 1 .$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\arccos\pars{\expo{-x}} & = y \implies
\expo{-x} = \cos\pars{y}
\end{align}
Since $\ds{\pars{~x \to 0 \implies \cos\pars{y} \to 1~}}$:
\begin{align}
&\pars{~1 - x \sim 1 - {1 \over 2}\,y^{2}\quad\mbox{as}\quad x \to 0~} \implies
\pars{~y \sim \root{2x}\quad\mbox{as}\quad x \to 0~}
\\[5mm] &\implies
\bbx{\ds{\arccos\pars{\expo{-x}} \sim \root{2x}\quad\mbox{as}\quad x \to 0}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the series $\enspace\displaystyle \cos\sqrt{2x}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{(2x)^k}{(2k)!}\enspace$ and $\enspace \displaystyle e^{-x}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k!}$ .

They have the linear part $\enspace 1-x\enspace$ common. The difference begins with the quadratic terms.

Comment: Can I estimate the difference of $\arccos(e^{-x})$ and $\sqrt{2x}$ based on these expansions ?

Comment: @Peter Sure, for small $x$ it is dominated by the difference of the quadratic terms.

Comment: @Ian: That gives you the difference between $e^{-x}$ and $\cos\sqrt{2x}$, not the difference between $\arccos(e^{-x})$ and $\sqrt{2x}$.

Comment: @TonyK Fair point, but you could run the same thing with $\arccos$ instead. You can't directly Taylor expand, but you can do the analogous thing (keeping in mind that $\arccos$ is not differentiable at $1$).

Comment: @Ian: It gets complicated, doesn't it? Just saying "the analogous thing" is dodging the issue.

Comment: @TonyK It doesn't really get complicated. The issue is just that you have to expand in non-integer powers because you don't have differentiability of $\arccos$ at $1$. But since we know $\cos''(0)$ is nonzero, it suffices to expand in half-integer powers, so that the problem reduces to finding the second coefficient in the power expansion of $\arccos$ at $1$.

Answer (score 1):

> **PRIMERS:**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753645/evaluation-of-limit-at-infinity), I showed using only elementary geometry that the arccosine function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$\sqrt{1-x^2}\le \arccos(x)\le \frac{1-x^2}{x} \tag 1$$
>
> for $0<x\le 1$.
>
> And in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x} \tag 2$$
>
> for $x<1$.

---

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, we have for $x<1$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2x}} \le \frac{\arccos(e^{-x})}{\sqrt{2x}}\le \frac{1}{1-x}$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem we obtain

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arccos(e^{-x})}{\sqrt{2x}}=1$$